# Mysql trigger that multiplies two values from different tables, totalizes by groups and adds values to another column

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been going around this for a while and there isno way I can figure it out. Let's say I have these three tables:

```
Users

Name   | Basket value
-------+---------------      
John   |     ???
-------+--------------- 
Pierre |     ???



Items

User       |     Item   |     Amount
-----------+------------+------------
  John     |    Pears   |       2
-----------+------------+------------
  Pierre   |    Pears   |       1
-----------+------------+------------
  Pierre   |   Apples   |       3


Market_ prices

Item        |        Price
------------+---------------
Pears       |        2.35
------------+---------------
Apples      |      2.56
```

Basket value is needed. So for each row in ITEMS it must multiply its `AMOUNT` by `MARKET_PRICES[PRICE]` and sum all the results grouped by `USER` and place this result in `USERS[total items value]`. But how could the syntax be elaborated to take this to practice?

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to join the relevant tables:

```
SELECT u.name, SUM(i.amount*m.price)
FROM users u 
JOIN items i ON u.name = i.user
JOIN market_prices m ON i.item = m.item
GROUP BY u.name;
```

(SQLfiddle of this is at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec224/6 - I added a few other rows to the tables to test more complexity, so the totals aren't what you'd get from your example. Specifically, I added `Bananas   3.75` to the Market_prices table and `John   Apples   3` and `Pierre   Bananas    5` to the Items table.)

The goal here is to link the information in all three tables through shared fields (via the JOIN), while also GROUPing and creating a SUM of the calculated costs as a product of market price and number of items.

---- edited based on comments ----
To do this as an update, you could try:

```
UPDATE users 
SET basket_value = (SELECT basket FROM
   (SELECT name, SUM(i.amount*m.price) AS basket
   FROM users u JOIN items i ON u.name = i.username 
   JOIN market_prices m ON i.item = m.item
   GROUP BY u.name) q1 WHERE q1.name = users.name);
```

I have a feeling there is a more elegant solution, but this works. Modified SQLFiddle is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56245a/1

Comment: Maybe you could update the basket value column in users instead of joining to it in the select.

Comment: Yes - that's possible. I wasn't actually clear on whether the users table intended as a table or a query result. There are a few issues with the DB structure that I ignored here.

Comment: Many thanks! Yes, the users table is indeed intended as a table.

Comment: By the way, do  you know why the basket_value is shown just once and turns to null after any update or refresh?

Comment: adjusted response to an update of user table. not sure what you mean with your most recent question.

Comment: What I meant is that if I edit  and raise pears' price, then Pierre's basket value should increase automatically, but it doesn't, it does  remain the same. It still happens with this secnd code. Many thanks!

Comment: i feel like it would be better to have basket_value generated from a query rather than be a table in its own right.

Comment: That's certainly an option, but still I think making it a table itself provides a number of advantages. I'm going to try to implement it via trigger... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT User, SUM(rev) AS basket_price
FROM
(
SELECT a.User AS User, a.Amount*b.Price AS rev 
FROM Items a
LEFT JOIN
Market_Prices b 
ON a.Item = b.Item
) a1
GROUP BY User
```

Comment: Could you do the same without the subselect?

Comment: Yep, I guess the subquery is redundant here.